# Table creation with Dash Framework

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am trying to build a dashboard where user can choose a pandas dataframe from the dropdown. Also they can search, sort, see the summary and download the data.

I have designed the dropdown many with the file names. Also added the dash.DataTable component. But I am not able to call the dataframe based on the value selected from dropdown.

Code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd


#df = pd.read_csv('data/chronos.csv')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='demo-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Chronos_data', 'value': 'chronos.csv'},
            {'label': 'CN_data', 'value': 'cn.csv'},
            {'label': 'Expression_data', 'value': 'expression.csv'}
        ],
        value='dataset'
    ),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-interactivity',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable="single",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=True,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 15,
        export_format='xlsx',
        export_headers='display',
        merge_duplicate_headers=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-interactivity', 'data'),
    [Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_output(dropdown_val):
    df_data = pd.read_csv('data/'+dropdown_val)
    return df_data

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-interactivity', 'style_data_conditional'),
    [Input('datatable-interactivity', 'selected_columns')]
)
def update_styles(selected_columns):
    return [{
        'if': { 'column_id': i },
        'background_color': '#D2F3FF'
    } for i in selected_columns]




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

```
Error: line 27, in <module>
    {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in df.columns
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't defined `df`. I'd recommend you pass the parameters `data` and `columns` from the callbacks directly as a list of dicts instead of adjusting them in the layout

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-interactivity', 'data'),
    Output('datatable-interactivity', 'columns'),
    [Input('demo-dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_output(dropdown_val):
    df_data = pd.read_csv('data/'+dropdown_val)
    return df_data, 
        [{"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": True, "selectable": True} for i in df_data.columns]
```